# Lego is 3rd conjugation but Relego is 1st

Tags: etymology

*Relego* seems to be related to *lego / legere* because it involves banishment. For example, *ablego* also means to banish.

However, relego is 1st conjugation and has a long E, so it would appear grammatically to be related more to lego / legare which means to bind or tie.

So, I don't understand this. Why would a verb derived from lego/legare have a meaning related to lego/legere?

Comment: Uhhm, surely it is related to *lego, -avi, -atum*, as is *ablego, -avi, -atum*. What does *legere* have to do with anything, or with banishing, for that matter?

Answer (score 9):

*Relēgō* (inf. *relēgāre*, 1st conj.) 'send away' is certainly from *lēgō* (inf. *lēgāre*) 'send with a comission', and so is *ablēgō* 'send away'.

*Relegō* (inf. *relegere*, 3rd conj.) 'gather again, recover' is from *legō* (inf. *legere*) 'gather', but does not mean 'banish'.

Neither *lēgō* (a denominal of *lēx*) nor *legō* means 'bind' or 'tie'. You may be thinking of *ligō* (inf. *ligāre*), which is etymologically unrelated to either.